# Native Database query isn't currently supported

Tags: powerbi

I am creating a new table by calling the stored Procedure in PowerBI, but it gives me an error.
Native Database query isn't currently supported

Below is my query which I am using to create a table. Calling an SP with clientname as a parameter.

If I run

```
EXEC dbo.Test 'Test'
```

It is working fine.

Created parameter for #ServerName.

```
= Sql.Database(#"ServerName", "MT", [Query="EXEC dbo.Test   " &"'" & ClientName &"'",CommandTimeout=#duration(250, 0, 0, 0)])
```

Googled about the error message and found 1 settings File > Options > Security > Unchecked required user approval for new native database queries.

But It still gives me an error.

Can someone please help.

Comment: parameter shall be only ``ServerName`` i guess...

Comment: like this ``Source = Sql.Database(dBaseIP, dBase , [Query=Query, CreateNavigationProperties=false])``

Comment: ClientName is also a parameter

Answer (score 0):

you can set the query text on the previous line and check if it is true, then you can run the query, like :

```
let

sQuery = "EXEC dbo.Test " & "'" & ClientName &"'",

RunQuery = Sql.Database( ServerName , "MT", [Query=sQuery,CommandTimeout=#duration(250, 0, 0, 0)])

in

RunQuery
```

on the other hand, they suggest using this syntax is better

```
myDB =Sql.Database(dBaseIP, dBase),
Source = Value.NativeQuery(mdDB, Query)
```